Azure Service Bus: Time Spent in Queue is Large
We have a .NET process where the process is subscribing to the Topic. One of the common observations is that the Time Spent in Queue is large.
Azure Service Bus is running with 2 Messaging Units. The usage of Service Bus is not high, but the messages are not being picked up. The Message Lock duration is 10-30 seconds for different queues.
The .NET code is running on AKS and is using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus and the code appears like,

ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient("connectionString",new ServiceBusClientOptions());

ServiceBusProcessorOptions clientOptions = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
            {
                AutoCompleteMessages = false
            };

ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor("topicName", "subscription", clientOptions);

processor.ProcessMessageAsync += ProcessMessageHandler;
processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorHandler;

processor.StartProcessingAsync();


The time spent in queue is too much even if we run multiple pods. What is potential reason for the delay?



There's not enough context to really even speculate.   The best that I can do is mention that the most common cause of this behavior in an AKS environment is too much concurrency for the CPU slice that he pod has.   I'd suggest opening an issue in the Azure SDK repository, as we'll want to collect Azure SDK logs for analysis, get additional insight into your application and host environment.  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues
